# Map webservice data properly into typescript object (mapping Objects with capital letters / pascal case to camel case)

Tags: json, angular, typescript, mapping

I realized a strange thing with my Angular2 typescript project. I have objects coming in from a webservice which have the type "Level" (it has the same properties as the Json coming from the webservice). In runtime comes out that the properties of the Level from the webservice have capital letters (Pascal case) at the beginning and the ones in my typescript project have small ones (visible in the browser's developer debug tool).

I guess I need to map the json properties somewhere somehow instead of doing a cast by writing "as Level[]" everywhere. How to I do it properly?

Update regarding the question that I should post some code:

(Controller)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.levelsObservable = this.levelsService.getAllLevels();
            this.levelsObservable.subscribe(
              data => console.log(data)
        );
  }
```

(Service)

```
observable : Observable<Response>;
getAllLevels(): Observable<Level[]> {
    this.observable =  this.achievementsService.getAllAchievements(this.allLevelsUrlPart);
    return this.observable
    .map((response: Response) => {
      const srcData = response.json() as Level[];
      return srcData;})
    .catch(error => this.handleError(error));}

getAllAchievements(detailPath): Observable<Response> {
// prepare request url and header
this.specificUrl = this.webServiceUrl + detailPath;
this.headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
this.result = this.http.get(this.specificUrl, options)
.catch(error => this.handleError(error));
return this.result;}
```

Update:
I polished my code a bit with the help of one answer below (not integrated above because not essential to solve the main problem).
I tried to use the other answer from below to reach the camel cases but it wasn't working (I have an array and in the array are objects with properties, but an object's properties aren't accessible with iterator methods).

Update: 
I finally managed it (!) :) I shortened this post a bit and will now post my solution below. It's for sure not the most beautiful, but I'm happy to have one after searching around for hours. Thanks to all people helping me with their great and input here!

Comment: update your post with code with out which we can't help

Comment: You need to write a function or method that takes the raw object from JSON and transforms it to a `Level`. Note that SO questions should have an [mcve] in them, not just a link to the whole codebase elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you, jonrsharpe. Can you explain how to do that? So where do I write this function and where do I call it best? I'll try to do a minimal example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally... I got a solution! For sure not the most beautiful one, but easy to understand and done with hard work and research:

```
private useLevelProperties (response: any): Level[]{
    let levels: Level[] = [];
     Object.keys(response).forEach((key) => {
       //create a new object and just take out the json parts needed. The webservice retrieves Pascal case letters, so we 
       //need to convert them into camel case ones.
      this.level = new Level(response[key]["AchievementId"], response[key]["Image"],
        response[key]["GrantedTo"], response[key]["GrantedBy"], response[key]["GrantedWhen"],  response[key]["Description"], 
        response[key]["Name"], response[key]["CompetitionCode"], response[key]["Number"]);

      levels[key] = this.level;
  });

     return levels;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get the lowercased objects.

```
  modifiedSrc(srcData){
    let obj = {};
    Object.keys(srcData).forEach((key)=>{
      obj[key.uncapitalize()] = srcData[key];
    })
    return obj
  }
  String.prototype.uncapitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + this.slice(1);
  }
```

Then you can return the modified data

```
getAllLevels(): Observable<Level[]> {
    this.observable =  this.achievementsService.getAllAchievements(this.allLevelsUrlPart);
    return this.observable
    .map((response: Response) => {
      const srcData = response.json() as Level[];
      return this.modifiedSrc(srcData);})
    .catch(error => this.handleError(error));}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand now where I have to put this stuff and how it works to get the properties in camel case. This approach is a bit too specific for my use case because it could be that I want to have only some of the json properties on my typescript object (3 of 10 e.g.) (when it comes to other achievements). How can I map the properties then?

Comment: I do not understand you clearly. Can you explain a bit more with an example or better , add a new question ?

Comment: I'll try to reformulate because I think it refers too much to the original question to open a new one: at the moment we are only converting all properties from the JSON object directly into a level with exactly the same properties (except the camel case letters at the beginning). What do I do if I have less properties on my typescript object than which are in the JSON? E.g. I have Id, Name, Number on the JSON and want name and number *only* to be on a Level in Typescript? Would it just work like this or do I need to do anything else except declaring only name and number on Level class?

Comment: This itself would . types only exist in compilation, after that its pure JS. And the modifiedSrc is created when the code runs. typescript doesnt have a way to understand its type. So you can use the same code. Or  if you want only the attributes you mentioned i request you to take a look into ``lodash``'s ``pick``. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If possible, I wouldn't like to install another framework only for this. The code from above doesn't work for me. I needed to initialize the "obj" as Level[] that I don't get a type complaint. But then, I get again the old properties. It can't work because I have a list of Levels[] and I need each property of the array members in camelCase. So the first key running through the loop is 0 (the array index). You would need an inner loop accessing each object's properties here, but it isn't possible to access them. So no working solution yet :(

Answer (score 0):

You have complicated both of your methods.Make it simple as

```
this.webServiceUrl = "http...." ;       // your service end point address
this.headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

// For all your error handling 
private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Internal Server error');
}
```

Your service method can use **TypeCasting** which will look like

```
getAllLevels(detailPath): Observable<Level[]> {
    return this.http.get(detailPath, options)
                  .map((response: Response) => <Level[]>response.json())
                  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Your component should raise the request to your service as

```
ngOnInit() : void{
        this._myService.getAllLevels()
                    .subscribe(levels => this.levels = levels,
                    error =>this.errorMessage =<any> error);

}
```

Your variable declaration must be like

```
levels:Level[];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your tips. I integrated them. Type Casting alone doesn't do the trick (unfortunately). I think this is because of the big and small letter difference.

Comment: you mean the **PascalCase** and **camelCase**

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do it server-side with an extra json option for camel case: [example for server-side camel casing](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4842)